# conditionally portforward on windows environment

Tags: windows, powershell, tcp, netcat

I am looking for a tool or a windows command to conditionally forward TCP/IP ports. The condition should be based on the requestors IP address.

I did that on Linux with the following command:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i eth0 -s 10.3.22.102   -d 10.3.22.11 --dport 1024 -j DNAT --to 10.3.22.9:5000
```

This time however I am in a windows environment.

I checked out netsh command but it cannot fullfil my requestor ip address condition. At least I couldn't find a solution for that.

Comment: `netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4` is the command you're looking for. It doesn't support conditional forwarding though, so you'll have to combine it with a firewall rule on the interface/port

Comment: thanks Mathias! Can you give me an example command for the windows firefall? I was looking in the UI an didn't really find a condition.

Comment: `netsh advfirewall firewall add rule` - allow inbound traffic on the listenport for the portproxy rule from the addresses you want to portforward for

Comment: Hi Mathias! Thanks again for your comment. If I understand you correct what you are proposing is if Host A is requesting I forward him. If Host B is requesting I deny him.

This is not what I am looking for. The logic I am looking for is: If Host A is requesting on port p1 use port p1. If Host B is requesting on port p1 forward the traffic to port p2.